# How to test a click event on a function sent through prop drilling

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a click event in my component that I am trying to test with `@testing-library/react`. This click event is being issued a function from the parent component, like so:

```
<DownloadButton>
  {handleDownload => (
     <ActionButton
      onClick={handleDownload}
      data-testid={CONFIG.TEST_IDS.BUTTONS.DOWNLOAD}
     >
      Download
     </ActionButton>
  )}
</DownloadButton>
```

I can `getByText` and `fireEvent.click` on the button, but unsure how to test if the `handleDownload` function actually fired.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand your question correctly you can't be sure if the `onClick` handler is called when you press your `ActionButton`?

another case that you want to test is if the `DownloadButton` provides the `handleDownload` render prop.

I would split the one test into two tests and separate each component on its own.

```
import React from "react";
import { DownloadButton, ActionButton } from "./App";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("DownloadButton", () => {
  it("returns handleDownloadFunction", () => {
    const childrenMock = jest.fn();
    render(<DownloadButton children={childrenMock} />);
    expect(childrenMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(childrenMock.mock.calls[0][0].handleDownload).toBeDefined();
  });
});

describe("ActionButton", () => {
  it("onClick invokes function", () => {
    const onClickMock = jest.fn();
    const { getByTestId, debug } = render(
      <ActionButton onClick={onClickMock} data-testid={"test-button"} />
    );
    debug();
    const button = getByTestId("test-button");

    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(onClickMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

for more detail take a look at the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-visvesvaraya-bkf6c?file=/src/App.test.js)

Comment: the first test we're covering in the unit test for `DownloadButton`. The second test doesn't seem to be testing the code, as we're overriding the onClick event with our own. Ideally we'd confirm that `handleDownload` was called. We want to test that when this button is clicked, `handleDownload` is called, not that when it's clicked it calls whatever we feed it to `onClick`. If a developer removes the `onClick={handleDownload}` then your test will still pass, won't it?

Comment: yes, indeed you're right. Does the `handleDownload` method call a certain logic outside the scope of `DownloadButton` or is the logic just inside the component? If we're dealing with the first case we could mock the dependency and ensure that it was called when we are rendering the `DownloadButton` with the `ActionButton`

Comment: It is calling code within `DownloadButton`, but to aim to keep this a unit test, I'd like just to know `ActionButton` did infact fire the function. I don't see how to mock `handleDownload`